# Check for entry in text fields and comboboxes to enable a button Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am writing a Java application for digitizing a group of documents in the office that I am working in and I am wanting to check if 5 textfields are populated and 4 combobox fields as well before the save button is enabled (I have it checking if i press a button (that happily says "Check"), but i would much rather have it auto-check to see if they are populated or if they are null).

If it makes a difference i am using NetBeans for this project.

Basically I need the fields to have something in them before the document can be saved.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated as this is the final step in creating this application... :D

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways (I can think of):

1- Put a listener on each field, this listener will be triggered when the field is populated. Inside the listener increment a counter for example, or set a flag. If all flags are set or if the counter reaches  (9 in your example) then enable the button.

2- Enable the Save button, but call a validate() method before doing the Save action. Any unpopulated field will have a red mark beside it (shown by validating) like in web applications.